# Does Applying Shape Caching to a Node, automatically Applies it to Children Nodes?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, javafx-2

So i'm trying to set caching for a stack pane that contains multiple buttons and labels, to try and improve the **performance** of the animation.

My question is, will applying caching to that stack pane, **automatically** apply it on all children nodes, that don't explicitly have the option turned off?